# Compare Dataframes Based on Column and Keep only common rows present in both dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am having two dataframes `df1`& `df2` as below.

```
import pandas as pd
data1 = [['1', 11], ['2', 12], ['3', 13],['5', 18],['8', 19]]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns=['Strike', 'Price'])
df1

Output-

    Strike  Price
0   1   11
1   2   12
2   3   13
3   5   18
4   8   19

data2 = [['1', 10], ['2', 15], ['4', 14],['8', 18]]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns=['Strike', 'Price'])
df2

Strike  Price
0   1   10
1   2   15
2   4   14
3   8   18
```

I want to compare column `Strike` of `df1` & `df2` and keep only rows which are having comman values present in `Strike` column of both `df1`,`df2` and reset index of both dataframes.

Expected Output-

```
df1
    Strike  Price
0   1   11
1   2   12
2   8   19

df2
Strike  Price
0   1   10
1   2   15
2   8   18
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

search df1 within df2 and then use location to identify the rows

```
df1.loc[df1['Strike'].isin(df2['Strike'])]
```

```
Strike  Price
0   1   11
1   2   12
4   8   19
```

same as above, just switch df1 with df2

```
df2.loc[df2['Strike'].isin(df1['Strike'])]
```

```
    Strike  Price
0   1   10
1   2   15
3   8   18
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this;

```
df3 = df1.merge(df2["Strike"],on="Strike",how="inner")
df4 = df2.merge(df1["Strike"],on="Strike",how="inner")
```

df3 & df4 are the outputs of df1 & df2 respectively.